# How to download multi files from same url with different code using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, download

For an example, I have this website :

```
www.mywebsite.domain.com
```

and my ending url for downloading files from it is like

```
/?download/downCode=493213
```

very non-sense just to simplify things, by changing the `downCode` at the end I can download any other file, so how do I develop a code in `PHP` that goes in a loop, downloading all files from the code `4000000` to `4999999` for an example?

I'm trying to use `PHP Multi cURL`, does it work just fine for what I need? What do you recommend?

Comment: curl or even though file_get_contents can work

Comment: What kind of file is it, have you a preference for a particular extension?

Comment: I did something similar with python a while ago... and I used it on ftp sites...

Comment: What is your script so far like?

Comment: My script is looking like this one so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMpCsfvi_3c . But modded, of course, with the loop. But there's the big deal, I cannot get the correct file extension, if the download URL ends with ?php/downCode=430203, the script uses this as the "file extension" instead of PDF.

What do you recommend to get the right file extension with this kind of URL?